# How to make Snowflake copy into that copies a file to copy it with the file_extension

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm running this query:

```
copy into @MY-S3-PATH/my-test5/
from
(select * from some.table limit 1)
    
FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = 'CSV' COMPRESSION = 'NONE' FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"' FILE_EXTENSION = 'csv')

single = True

MAX_FILE_SIZE = 100000
overwrite = False

include_query_id = False
detailed_output = false
        
header = True;
```

and after the file end up in the bucket just as "data" and not "data.csv" like I specified in the query.
what should I do to make it "data.csv"?

Comment: Hi - this is explained in the documentation. Try reading the note under the FILE_EXTENSION parameter: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location

Comment: I've read it but it's unclear to me

Comment: Hi - what is unclear about this: “ If the SINGLE copy option is TRUE, then the COPY command unloads a file without a file extension by default. To specify a file extension, provide a file name and extension in the internal_location or external_location path. For example:

copy into @stage/data.csv ...”? You’re using “single=true” so you need to provide the file name and extension in the location